# Why does the logstash pod continually fail for the elastic-stack Helm chart?

Tags: elastic-stack, kubernetes-helm

I would like to use a full elastic stack instance on a production grade Kubernetes cluster managed by GKE. I'm pretty new to Kubernetes in general but especially Helm.

I have tried running the following for both versions 1.6.0 and 1.5.1 of the following chart:

`helm install stable/elastic-stack --version 1.5.1 --name test-elastic`

Most of the pods seem to spin up fine, except for the `StatefulSet` `test-elastic-logstash`, where the pod within seems to fail with a reproducible `CrashLoopBackOff` error. The readiness probe seems to continually fail with `connection refused`, but that's not something I find especially constructive.

Could anyone please offer any thoughts on what's required to get this working?

Comment: I am not familiar with the elk stack, but what I would do is try to open a shell on the logstash container (with 'kubectl exec') and run the commands it tries to do to connect, probably those environment variables for the ES host and port, they should be correct and you are able to connect to the ES

Comment: I'll have a go at that, thank you!